# Show article details from custom module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, mysql, xml, module-params

I am trying to develop a custom module where I have options to select 4 different Joomla articles.

In my module XML file, I have the following:

```
<field name="articleOne"
    type="sql"
    label="Select an article"
    query="SELECT id AS value, title AS articleOne FROM #__content"
/>

<field name="articleTwo"
    type="sql"
    label="Select an article"
    query="SELECT id AS value, title AS articleOne FROM #__content"
/>

<field name="articleThree"
    type="sql"
    label="Select an article"
    query="SELECT id AS value, title AS articleOne FROM #__content"
/>

<field name="articleFour"
    type="sql"
    label="Select an article"
    query="SELECT id AS value, title AS articleOne FROM #__content"
/>
```

I can get this to output the ID in the frontend. But how can I output the title, introtext and image?

I would like it to display in the frontend as follows:

[image]

Comment: Can you give us more of an idea about how would see this being displayed? Is it a series of article title/introtext/image combinations from which the user can select 4 using checkboxes? It seems a lot to put into a module. Or are you wanting an html select input field which allows the user to select 4? Again, it's all not going to fit into that.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the SQL form field will always return the ID of an article.

So you can get the title, into text and intro image, you can use Joomla's `Table` class:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Table\Table;

$array = ['articleOne', 'articleTwo', 'articleThree', 'articleFour'];

// Loop through each array item
foreach ($array as $value)
{
    $article = Table::getInstance('content'); 
    $article->load($params->get($value));
    $articleImages = json_decode($article->get('images'));

    // Check if an intro image exists
    if (isset($articleImages->image_intro))
    {
        echo '<img src="' . $articleImages->image_intro . '" alt="">';
    }
    echo $article->get('title');
    echo $article->get('introtext');
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Lodder, this is great but it's only showing the first article?

Comment: @RustyJoomla Updated the code. Make sure you have selected an article for all four parameters